# Django image is not uploading from the template, but uploads from admin

Tags: html, django, upload, image-uploading

I am trying to create a page where the users can upload an image with their post.
The image upload is working in another app, but in this one, whenever I submit the form, all the info except the image are inserted into the database.
If I open the admin panel and upload an image, the image is uploaded successfully, it is only throught the template that I am not able to upload.

Here is my model:

```
def validate_image(image):
    file_size = image.file.size
    limit_mb = 3
    if file_size > limit_mb * 1048576:
        raise ValidationError("Max size of file is %s MB" % limit_mb)

class Posting (models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='poster_posting', verbose_name='poster')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('description'))
    pictures = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='postings/',
        verbose_name=_('Posting_picture'),
        blank=True, null=True,
        validators=[validate_image],
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "Posting #{}".format(self.pk)

    def filename(self):
        if self.pictures:  
            return os.path.basename(self.pictures.name)
        return ''
```

Here is the view:

```
def posting(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
        form = Publish(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.poster = request.user
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, _("your request was posted successfully"))


            return redirect("posting:posting_detail", pk=post.id)
    else:
        form = Publish()

    return render (request, 'list_posting.html',{'form': form})
```

The form:

```
class Publish(forms.ModelForm):
    """publishing of listing"""
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': 6, }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Posting
        fields = (
        'description',
        'pictures')
```

and finally the template:

```
[...]
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom: 60px;font-family: Muli, sans-serif;" >
 {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-row" id="Notes" style="padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 20px;">
                <div class="col"><input name="description" id="listing_description" required class="form-control" placeholder=" {% trans 'Items to send - Example: I want to send 3 shirts, one children book and one science book (maximum of 150 characters)' %}" maxlength="150" style="margin-top: 36px;"></div>

{% if form.description.errors %}<small class="form-text text-muted" style="color: red">{{ form.description.errors }}</small> {% endif %}


                      </div>

<div class="form-row" id="Pictures" style="padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 20px;" >
    <div class="col">

    <input accept="image/" type="file" class="filestyle" name="pictures" data-size="sm" style="padding-top: 33px;" >
<small class="form-text text-muted" >{% trans 'You can only upload one picture. The size cannot exceed 3Mb.' %}</small> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row text-right" id="Buttons" style="padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 29px;">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group"><a class="btn btn-light" role="button" href="{% url '...' %}" style="margin-right: 20px;">{%trans 'cancel'%}</a><button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">{% trans 'submit' %}</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I submit the form, in the debug, the pictures field is blank, so I am not sure if the issue is within my html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that you didn't attach `pictures` to your form. Change how you build your form to:

views.py:

```py
form = Publish(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

You can also improve your template a little bit if you follow [django docs on forms rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

How did you even create `ForeignKey` without `on_delete` attribute?

In your model, you refer to user as poster, not as sender, so change it as well:

views.py:

```py
post.poster = request.user
```

Comment: Thank you @Gasanov, can you just explain to me the thing with the on_delete attribute? In my case, the key will not be deleted from the database, so I did not take into account the on_delete, but should I always add it when there is a foreign key?

Comment: @RiadC `on_delete` is [positional argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), as far as I know, django shouldn't even start without specifying it (unless you using django <=1.8, in which case you should update your version - it's very outdated)

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your settings.py configurations?
Also you need to include `form = Publish(request.POST, request.FILES or none)` in views.py for rendering files or images in your forms.py